# Как сделать табы у которых навигация — чекбоксы?

Tags: css

Как сделать табы, у которых навигация - `<input type="chekbox">`?
Очень специфично, но требуется.
Задача, чтобы при клике на кнопку одной вкладки, она выделилась галочкой и одновременно отображала свой контент, рядом с ней - такая же. Нажимаешь на нее - тоже активируется чекбокс, отображается соответствующий кнопке контент.
Спасибо!
К сожалению, как ни пытался - чекбокс остается неактивным при клике

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981934/javascript-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-css

Comment: @user354190 к сожалению,там кнопки,нужны именно чекбоксы и чтобы не мьютились

Comment: @Вы уверены что пункт 3. Варианты на CSS. не подходят ?